# Angular, change class variable/property with function

Tags: angular

Can't believe I am asking this, but I did not find an answer to this problem.
As you can guess I am fairly new to Angular.

How can I change `public slideNumber = 1` dynamically within a class?

```
    export class TestimonialComponent {
  public slideNumber = 1;

  Carousel() {
    setInterval(function () {
      this.slideNumber = 9;
    }, 1000);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.Carousel();
    this.slideNumber = 3;
  }
}
```

from my understanding ngOnInit shares slideNumber with the class, but the Carousel function declares its own slideNumber.

My question is why does this happen and how can I *dynamically* change the first declared variable in the class? (`public slideNumber = 1`)

### Clarification

- ngOnInit changes the `public slideNumber = 1` to 3
- Carousel function creates it's own property `this.slideNumber = 9`

This means that `public slideNumber = 1` is now 3 and Carousel is not able to interact with `public slideNumber = 1`

Comment: `ngOnInit` is a lifecycle hook, not sure what you mean about "shares slideNumber with the class". Is `Carousel` just a function? Need more info and preferrably a reproducible example (template code etc)

Comment: @Phix Thanks for reaching out! yes Carousel is just a function. However, the Carousel's `this.slideNumber` is independent from the class's `public slideNumber = 1` Does that help? if not i will provide some more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `Carousel` to

```
Carousel() {
    setInterval(() =>{
      this.slideNumber = 9;
    }, 1000);
  }
```

When using `function(){}` , it makes a new `this` that depends on how it being called. when using arrow syntax `() => {}`, `this` is same as parent's.

For more info, check out https://itnext.io/the-this-keyword-in-javascript-demystified-c389c92de26d

Comment: Hmm, i see! thank you! Would you care to add an explanation?

Comment: @Stanley, ur welcome. I just updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! This is embarrassing, I guess you live and learn. Great explanation! I will accept the answer once the timer goes out

Comment: @Stanley. Always consider using es6 syntax in Angular.

Comment: @Akhil yeah, this was totally my bad! I forgot how to setInterval and found and old article and just copied the first thing I found. And I was certain this problem was caused by angular syntax I didn't know haaha.

Answer (score 0):

make slideNumber an @Input variable. or add a method

```
setSlideNumber(num:number) {
  this.slideNumber = num;
}
```

and then use a ViewChild to set it. there's no reason to have hard coded numbers in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the reason the numbers were hardcoded were due to simplicity.